Why does my Mac's system partition slowly fill up with msu-target-xxxxxxxxx folders in the /private/tmp folder?
I notice that if I leave my Mac mini (running MacOS Sonoma 14.5) running for a long period (e.g. several weeks, with lots of time spend asleep), I will eventually start getting "you are low on disk space" messages, which is odd since I haven't been doing anything that would use up significantly more disk space.
If I then run DaisyDisk to see where all my space has gone too, it looks like there are a number of folders named msu-target-xxxxxxxxx (where the x's are actually a series of random letters and numbers) appearing in my /private/tmp folder.  The folders appear to contain copies (or partial copies?) of my system partition, possibly with hardlinks?  Doing a soft reboot of the Mac clears my /private/tmp folder and gets me my drive space back.
My questions are:  Why are these folders appearing and taking up space on my drive, and what can I do to avoid this misbehavior?
Screenshots of my system before I did the reboot (with just 737MB of free space available on the HD) and immediately after the reboot (now with 4.42GB of free space available) are included below, in case there is some telling detail to be seen there.



You might need to free up another 15 GB of space on that volume and reboot and let the system catch up with downloads and cleanup. You’re so tight on space, things will break that normally self correct.

Enter the following command in a Terminal window:
sudo fs_usage -ew -f filesys | grep msu-target

Leave the Terminal window open.  The next time one of the folders is created, some lines of output should appear with the name of the process that created it.

Thanks, I did that and after a couple of minutes I got some output which I've uploaded here in case you want to look at it:  https://public.msli.com/lcs/jaf/msu-logs.txt  -- it doesn't mean much to me, outside of that it appears to at least be macOS services accessing the msu-target folder and not anything third-party.

I'm guessing msu is short for MobileSoftwareUpdate, i.e. macOS trying to download a new OS update for me?

Sorry, I misread the folder name in your question. It's not third-party software. You don't have enough space available on the internal storage to download a system update. You need at least about 15 GB of free space to update successfully.

Yes, this turned out to be the case -- I freed up some hard drive space and then manually triggered an OS update to 14.6.1, and now the odd behavior seems to be gone.  Thank you for your help!
